# How to create a client jar in websphere without having the server running?

Tags: websphere

I have a requirement for my R&D which seems to be tricky.

I want to create a client jar for an EJB application.

Consider that I have an `EJB` application and its jars with me. I just need to create a client jar for that `EJB` application.

To create it, I need the server to be running. But my requirement is that, I have to create the jar without having the server started.

I tried few stuffs but the adminclient creation tries to create a `SOAP` connector port at a specified address which is failing for me.

**PS:** I am trying this expt on Windows platform.

Comment: Just an advice: Do not include more than 2 'question marks [?]' in your question.  Actually, 1 is just enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use astk (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg24007418)

> import ear -> right-click jar-> generate client jar.